# Matrix Computation Without loops

Tags: r, loops, matrix, apply

I want to make a matrix according to this formula:

[image]

I've written this code for this matrix:

```
V <- function(x,z){
  V <- matrix(NA,nrow(x),nrow(x))

  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    for(j in 1:nrow(x)){

      d11 <- apply(z,1,FUN = function(y) ((z-x[i,])))
      d12 <- apply(z,1,FUN = function(y) ((z-x[j,])))
      d1 <- d11*d12
      d2 <- apply(d1, 2 , prod)
      d3 <- sum(d2)

      V[i,j]= d3
    }
  }

  return(V)
}
```

But, I need to make this matrix without loops and less computation cost.

Comment: What is italic capital I in the formula?

Comment: Also provide reproducible examples of `Z` and `X` and what the results should look like.

Comment: Is the `y` a typo in `FUN = function(y) ((z-x[i,]))` ?